# Replace Data with NA

Tags: r, replace, na

```
fct<- function(x){volume03[[x]][which(is.na(last03[[x]]))]<- NA}
lapply(1:length(volume03, fct)
```

I want to set all of those numbers within volume03 to NA, which are NA in last03. However, R is returning a list of only NAs.

Why I am trying to do that: The data is stock data (zoo series) -

```
volume[[1]][1]
```

returning data for company 1 on day one. Some of the data is zero, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, you can just do

```
for (i in 1:length(volume03)) volume03[[i]][is.na(last03[[i]])] <- NA
```

Indices can be easily operated explicitly:

```
    l=c(NA, 1, 2);k=c(3, 5, 6)
    > i.l=is.na(l)
    > i.l
    [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
    > k[i.l]=NA
    > k
    [1] NA  5  6
    > l=c(NA, 1, 2);k=c(3, 5, 6)
    > k[is.na(l)]=NA
    > k
    [1] NA  5  6
```